# Try to solve integral $\int \frac{3-7z}{21z^2-7}dz$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

$$\int \frac{3-7z}{21z^2-7}dz$$
I would like to get some advice how to solve this integral

Comment: For the expression $\frac{3-7z}{21z^2-7}$, split it into partial fraction in the form $\frac{A}{\sqrt{3}z+1} + \frac{B}{\sqrt{3}z-1}$, where $A$ and $B$ are constants.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Maths.SE. I have changed the formatting of the title so as to make it take up less vertical space -- this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions. See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9730) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future questions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Lord_Farin OK,THANKS! . freak_warrior I didn't understand your answer :\

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use **[partial fraction decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fractions)** to break the integral down:

$$\int \frac{3-7z}{21z^2-7}\,dz = \int \frac{3- 7z}{7(3z^2 - 1)}\,dz = \int \frac 17\left(\frac{A}{\sqrt{3}z+1} + \frac{B}{\sqrt{3}z-1}\right)\,dz$$

Now just solve for the constants $A, B$: $$A(\sqrt 3 z - 1) + B(\sqrt 3 z + 1) = 3 - 7z$$

Comment: Short and sweet! +1

Answer (score 0):

You may find the method of **[Partial Fractions](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/PartialFractions.aspx)** useful to work with the integrand.